# Is there any way to justify text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to justify text in a cell in Google Sheets. I searched Google and have no clue how because there are only 3 choices of alignment: left, center and right. Do you have any ideas or ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is less *in* Sheets than *on* Sheets, but you can use "Insert > Drawing" and then create a "Text box" and choose the "Justify" option under "Align", which is found in the ellipsis (three vertical dots: "...") menu:

[image: toolbar with text underneath]

Result:

[image: lorem ipsum justified over 3 columns]